# Dhalion running on Heron by default?

Tags: streaming, heron

I trying to figure out if Dhalion runs on Heron by Default in all of the versions of the heron incubator project. I see that there is Dhalion is merged in the Heron Repo, but it's not really clear from the documentation as to whether Dhalion is actually running on Heron by default for self-regulation or if it should be started manually.
Docs - https://apache.github.io/incubator-heron/docs/getting-started/
Repo - https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron

Any insights into this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, Dhalion is not enabled by default. You need to add these two arguments for heron-executor:

1. --health-manager-mode=enabled
2. --health-manager-classpath=...

In your cluster config, you also need a healthmgr.yaml file to config the policy. In github, the local cluster has an example config:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron/blob/master/heron/config/src/yaml/conf/local/healthmgr.yaml